# Elixir/Erlang: Error when a variable list merge with many other lists

Tags: list, erlang, elixir, elixir-iex

I have this function:

```
defp get_list(map, l, i) do

    list = l ++ map
```

where **map** is the new list who comes every repetition, so **l** is merged with it and attributed to **list**

it works great for a small number of pages, the problem is when lots of pages are being merged, some time after the lists are beind added to **list** the following error accurs:

**(ArgumentError) argument error
:erlang.++([0.33966522437570745,...]) (api_sort 0.1.0) lib/api_sort.ex:18: ApiSort.get_list/3**

Comment: Which line is line 18? Is it the one with `list = l ++ map`?

Comment: Hi. Are you sure that the arguments are always correct in terms of type? `Argument error` can be raised if the argument types are not what the BEAM expect.

Comment: Yes, line 18 is this one! Well, thr format is always the same, two lists [] merger into one bigger list.

Answer (score 0):

The prolem was that some of the 'maps' who comes from a site are not list type, even though they are all between [], so i made a condition is_list(map) and it prevented these fake lists to cause the error.